Can solution of heat equation become constant in finite time
Consider parabolic equation
$$
u_t = u_{xx},
$$
where $x \in (0, 1)$, $t \in (0, T)$ with nonhomogenious Dirichlet boundary conditions.
$$
u(0, t) = \psi_0(t) \in C^0,
$$
$$
u(1, t) = \psi_1(t) \in C^0.
$$
Assume that initial data
$$
u(x, 0) = \varphi(x)
$$
is smooth and not constant,
Is it possible that in finite time $t_0$
$$
u(x, t_0) \equiv C, \quad x \in (0, 1).
$$
ANSWER: Yes, it can

As it stands, the answer is obviously yes. Just pick u to be whatever you want it to be and then choose f accordingly. But this is probably not what you intended.

Yes, indeed. I have some restrictions on $f$. It is an indicator of a certain set in $(x, t)$. I am editing question.

It seems that Feymann-Kac formula helps with backward solution of
$u_t = -u_{xx}$, which is a lot different.

@SergeyTikhomirov it works for both, see the answer in the above link.

Not only is this possible, but more is true: For any initial datum, there exist boundary data which make it so. Google "boundary null controllability" for the heat equation.

Thank you. Yes it works.
